# Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager returns no results when searching proxied repositories

Tags: maven, repository, nexus

I just installed the Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager 3 on my Mac os. It starts up fine on port 8081 and has several pre-configured repositories, including maven central and nuget.org-proxy, both proxies and with status of online-available. So far so good, but when I try even simple searches for commonly available java jar files (or anything else) I get no results. I tried reindexing (no effect) and there are no errors in the logs. Checking the configurations, the proxy urls, when pasted in a browser, show me all the components in these repositories.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.